# Inserting values of two different tables into new table using same IDs MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have 3 tables, table1 and table2 have data. I need to push/insert these data into other tables.

PFA image:

[image]

PLZ help me to get final resultant table

Thanks in advance

I am tried node.js

Here table1 is companyAsc,table2 personAsc, and table3 country_associate

connection.query('SELECT * FROM companyAsc', function(err, rows, fields)
        {

```
        if (!err) {
            if(rows.length == 0){
            }else{

                var str = JSON.stringify(rows)
                var parsed2 = JSON.parse(str);

                connection.query('SELECT * FROM personAsc', function(err, rows, fields)
                {

                    if (!err) {
                        if(rows.length == 0){

                        } else{

                            var str = JSON.stringify(rows)
                            var parsed3 = JSON.parse(str);
                            //company_id = parsed2[0].id;
                            if(parsed2.length>parsed3.length){
                                console.log("1")

                                for(i=0;i<parsed2.length;i++){
                                    var person_id;
                                        var company_id  = parsed2[i].company_id;
                                        var country_id  = parsed2[i].country_id;

                                        if(parsed3[i]!=undefined){
                                            person_id  = parsed3[i].person_id;
                                        }else{
                                            person_id  = 3725;
                                        }

                                        connection.query('insert into country_associate(country_id,company_id,person_id) values ("'+country_id+'","'+company_id+'","'+person_id+'")',function(err, rows, fields){
                                            if (err) console.log(err);
                                            else{
                                                console.log("inserted");
                                            }
                                        });      

                                    }
                            } else{
                                for(i=0;i<parsed3.length;i++){
                                    var company_id;
                                    //var person_id  = parsed3[i].person_id;
                                    var country_id  = parsed3[i].country_id;
                                    if(parsed2[i]!=undefined){
                                        company_id  = parsed2[i].company_id;
                                    }else{
                                        company_id  = 1317;
                                    }

                                    if(parsed3[i]!=undefined){
                                        person_id  = parsed3[i].person_id;
                                    }else{
                                        person_id  = 3725;
                                    }

                                    connection.query('insert into country_associate(country_id,company_id,person_id) values ("'+parsed2[i].country_id+'","'+company_id+'","'+person_id+'")',function(err, rows, fields){
                                        if (err) console.log(err);
                                        else{
                                            console.log("inserted");
                                        }
                                    });

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }else{
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                });

            }

        }else{
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have tried joins, all type of joins i tried. but i am not getting final result as shown in image

Comment: I tried in node.js. i will add code

Comment: OK. DV reversed and upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Since MySql doesn't support full outer join use union, they are equivalent

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (A, B, C)
SELECT Table1.A, Table1.B, Table2.C FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.A
UNION
SELECT Table1.A, Table1.B, Table2.C FROM Table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.A
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.. but full outer join is not supporting in MySQL

Comment: i have edited and added union instead of full outer join, you can try that

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table3 (a, b, c)
(SELECT  table1.a, table1.b, table2.c 
from table1, table2
where table1.a = table2.a);
```

Your question is not clear, what have you tried ?